# Conditional assignment of one variable to the value of one of two other variables

Tags: r

I want to create a new variable that is equal to the value of one of two other variables, conditional on the values of still other variables. Here's a toy example with fake data.

Each row of the data frame represents a student. Each student can be studying up to two subjects (`subj1` and `subj2`), and can be pursuing a degree ("BA") or a minor ("MN") in each subject. My real data includes thousands of students, several types of degree, about 50 subjects, and students can have up to five majors/minors.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:20,
  subj1 = factor(c(
    "SCI", NA, "BUS", "ENG", "ENG", "SCI", "ENG", "BUS", "ENG",
    "ENG", "BUS", "ENG", "BUS", "BUS", "BUS", "SCI", "SCI", "BUS",
    "ENG", "BUS"
  )),
  degree1 = factor(rep(c("MN", NA, "BA", "MN", "BA"), c(1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 13L))),
  subj2 = factor(c(
    "BUS", "ENG", NA, NA, "BUS", NA, "SCI", "ENG", NA, "ENG", "ENG",
    "BUS", "SCI", NA, "ENG", "BUS", "BUS", NA, "ENG", "ENG"
  )),
  degree2 = factor(c(
    "MN", "MN", NA, NA, "MN", NA, "BA", "MN", NA, "MN", "BA", "BA",
    "MN", NA, "BA", "MN", "MN", NA, "BA", "MN"
  ))
)
df
#>    ID subj1 degree1 subj2 degree2
#> 1   1   SCI      MN   BUS      MN
#> 2   2  <NA>    <NA>   ENG      MN
#> 3   3   BUS      BA  <NA>    <NA>
#> 4   4   ENG      BA  <NA>    <NA>
#> 5   5   ENG      BA   BUS      MN
#> 6   6   SCI      MN  <NA>    <NA>
#> 7   7   ENG      MN   SCI      BA
#> 8   8   BUS      BA   ENG      MN
#> 9   9   ENG      BA  <NA>    <NA>
#> 10 10   ENG      BA   ENG      MN
#> 11 11   BUS      BA   ENG      BA
#> 12 12   ENG      BA   BUS      BA
#> 13 13   BUS      BA   SCI      MN
#> 14 14   BUS      BA  <NA>    <NA>
#> 15 15   BUS      BA   ENG      BA
#> 16 16   SCI      BA   BUS      MN
#> 17 17   SCI      BA   BUS      MN
#> 18 18   BUS      BA  <NA>    <NA>
#> 19 19   ENG      BA   ENG      BA
#> 20 20   BUS      BA   ENG      MN
```

Now I want to create a sixth variable, `df$major`, that equals the value of `subj1` if `subj1` is the student's primary major, or the value of `subj2` if `subj2` is the primary major. The primary major is the first subject with degree equal to "BA". I tried the following code:

```
df$major[df$degree1 == "BA"] = df$subj1
df$major[df$degree1 != "BA" & df$degree2 == "BA"] = df$subj2
```

Unfortunately, I got an error message:

```
> df$major[df$degree1 == "BA"] = df$subj1
Error in df$major[df$degree1 == "BA"] = df$subj1 : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

I assume this means that a vectorized assignment can't be used if the assignment evaluates to NA for at least one row.

I feel like I must be missing something basic here, but the code above seemed like the obvious thing to do and I haven't been able to come up with an alternative.

Comment: There are rows where both degree1 and degree2 are BA. What should the major column be in those cases?

Comment: If deg1="BA" then subj1 is the primary major. If deg1!="BA" & deg2=="BA", then subj2 is the primary major. In terms of the problem I'm having, the specific conditions for selecting the primary major aren't as important as the reason why this method of assignment fails.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your original method of assignment is failing for at least two reasons.

1) A problem with the subscripted assignment `df$major[df$degree1 == "BA"] <-`. Using `==` can produce `NA`, which is what prompted the error. From `?"[<-"`: "When replacing (that is using indexing on the lhs of an assignment) NA does not select any element to be replaced. As there is ambiguity as to whether an element of the rhs should be used or not, this is only allowed if the rhs value is of length one (so the two interpretations would have the same outcome)." There are many ways to get around this, but I prefer using `which`:

```
df$major[which(df$degree1 == "BA")] <-
```

The difference is that `==` returns `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NA`, while `which` returns the indices of an object that are TRUE

```
> df$degree1 == "BA"
 [1] FALSE    NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

> which(df$degree1 == "BA")
 [1]  3  4  5  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

2) When you perform a subscripted assignment, the right hand side needs to fit into the left hand side sensibly (this is the way I think of it). This can mean left and right hand sides of equal length, which is what your example seems to imply. Therefore, you would need to subset the right hand side of the assignment as well:

```
df$major[which(df$degree1 == "BA")] <- df$subj1[which(df$degree1 == "BA")]
```

---

I hope that clarifies why your original attempt produced an error.

Using `ifelse`, as suggested by @DavidRobinson, is a good way of doing this type of assignment. My take on it:

```
df$major2 <- ifelse(df$degree1 == "BA", df$subj1, ifelse(df$degree2 == "BA",
  df$subj2,NA))
```

This is equivalent to

```
df$major[which(df$degree1 == "BA")] <- df$subj1[which(df$degree1 == "BA")]
df$major[which(df$degree1 != "BA" & df$degree2 == "BA")] <- 
  df$subj2[which(df$degree1 != "BA" & df$degree2 == "BA")]
```

Depending on the depth of the nested `ifelse` statements, another approach might be better for your real data.

---

**EDIT:**

I was going to write a third reason for the original code failing (namely that `df$major` wasn't yet assigned), but it works for me without having to do that. This was a problem I remember having in the past, though. What version of R are you running? (2.15.0 for me.) This step is not necessary if you use the `ifelse()` approach. Your solution is fine when using `[`, although I would have chosen

```
df$major <- NA
```

To get the character values of the subjects, instead of the factor level index, use `as.character()` (which for factors is equivalent to and calls `levels(x)[x]`):

```
df$major[which(df$degree1 == "BA")] <- as.character(df$subj1)[which(df$degree1 == "BA")]
df$major[which(df$degree1 != "BA" & df$degree2 == "BA")] <- 
  as.character(df$subj2)[which(df$degree1 != "BA" & df$degree2 == "BA")]
```

Same for the `ifelse()` way:

```
df$major2 <- ifelse(df$degree1 == "BA", as.character(df$subj1),
  ifelse(df$degree2 == "BA", as.character(df$subj2), NA))
```

Comment: Second, when I tried the "which" method, I got a result I didn't expect. Instead of df$major being set to the appropriate df$subj1 values, df$major was assigned a number, either 1, 2, or 3. At first I thought these corresponded to the factors in df$subj1, but there was no rhyme or reason to which numbers in df$major went with the corresponding value of df$subj1. Here's what I ran (on the data in my question): df1$major[which(df1$degree1=="BA")] <- df1$subj1[which(df1$degree1=="BA")].

Comment: (continuation of previous comment) (I should also mention that before running the code above, I typed df$major="None" to intialize df$major, otherwise the assignment to df$major gives an error.) Correction to my previous comment: The numbers in df$major _do_ correspond to the factor values in `df$subj1`. So, my question is: how do I get the actual factor values in `df$major`, rather than numbers corresponding to the factor values?

Comment: I'm running version 2.14.1. Thanks for adding the edit and for an overall great answer!

Answer (score 8):

In general, the [ifelse](http://www.math.montana.edu/Rweb/Rhelp/ifelse.html) function is the right choice for these situations, something like:

```
df$major = ifelse((!is.na(df$degree1) & df$degree1 == "BA") & (is.na(df$degree2) | df$degree1 != "BA"), df$subj1, df$subj2)
```

However, its precise use depends on what you do if both `df$degree1` and `df$degree2` are "BA".

Comment: David, in my actual data set, students can also have "pre-majors" if they haven't been formally admitted to a major. If a student has only a pre-major, I would assign that as their primary major. But if they have both a pre-major and a major, I would assign the major as their primary major. Can `ifelse` statements be nested to handle complex possibilities like that?

Comment: Yes: a typical nested example would look something like `ifelse(A, B, ifelse(C, D))`