# New variable with values depending on combination of other variables

Tags: r

I'm very inexperienced in R, and although this site has been tremendously helpful, I have a very specific situation and cannot find a solution. I imagine I need to write a function to accomplish this. However, my current time frame does not allow me to spend the time doing trial/error. (I apologize in advance for anything unclear).

Here is an example of my current data:

```
UniqueID, Time1.Feel1, Time2.Feel1.1, Time2.Feel1.2, Time2Num
1, 9, 5, 6, 1
1, 9, 7, 5, 2
2, 4, 3, 4, 1
2, 4, 5, 6, 2
3, 7, 4, 7, 1
3, 7, 6, 5, 2
```

I want to create a new variable: Time2.Feel1, which consists of the values of either Time2.Feel1.1 OR Time2.Feel1.2, depending on the value of Time2Num.

So, this:

```
UniqueID, Time1.Feel1, Time2.Feel1.1, Time2.Feel1.2, Time2Num, Time2.Feel1
1, 9, 5, 6, 1, 5
1, 9, 7, 5, 2, 5
2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3
2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6
3, 7, 4, 7, 1, 4
3, 7, 6, 5, 2, 5
```

I need to do this 30 times (i.e., Time2Num has values 1:30 and there are 30 different Time2.Feel1 variables: Time2.Feel1.1:30)

I then want to calculate a correlation between Time1.Feel1 and Time2.Feel1 for EACH UniqueID, creating a new data frame with the variables UniqueID and the new correlations. This part is less of a concern; I think I've figured out how to that, but if the combined steps could be done more simply, I'd prefer that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't have time to flesh it out, but something like `dat$Time2.Feel1 <- dat[c("Time2.Feel1.1","Time2.Feel1.2")][cbind(seq(nrow(dat)),dat$Time2Num)]` will do it all in one go.

Comment: When I tried this I got the error: Error in as.matrix(x)[i] : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

When searching for the error I received when trying the answer from @user12202013, I came across this solution using `ifelse`, found here: [Conditional assignment of one variable to the value of one of two other variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489586/conditional-assignment-of-one-variable-to-the-value-of-one-of-two-other-variable)

```
Time2.Feel1 <- ifelse(Time2Num == 1, Time2.Feel1.1, ifelse(Time2Num == 2,
Time2.Feel1.2,""))
```

Although it is definitely not the most efficient solution, particularly because I need to nest it 30 times and I need to do it for 9 items, it solved my problem. A simpler answer is still welcome, though!

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like:

```
Time2.Feel1 = rep(NA, length(Time2Num))
Time2.Feel1[Time2Num == 1] <- Time2.Feel1.1
Time2.Feel1[Time2Num == 2] <- Time2.Feel1.2
```

This says to create a vector called `Time2.Feel1` which we initialize with NA values. Then where `Time2Num` is one we fill in the values from `Time2.Feel1.1` and where `Time2Num` is two we fill in the values from `Time2.Feel1.2`. If there is any place where `Time2Num is neither 1 nor 2 then`Time2.Feel1` will have an NA value.

Edit:

Not sure what the error message is referring to since I am able to do this

```
# reproducible example
set.seed(1)
A <- letters
B <- sample(c(0, 1, NA), 26, TRUE)
A[B == 1] <- '5' # assignment where subscript contains NAs
A[B == 0] <- NA  # assigning NA values
A
[1] NA  "5" "5" "d" NA  "f" "g" "5" "5" NA  NA  NA  "m" "5" "o" "5" "q" "r" "5" "t" "u" NA  "5" NA  NA  "5"
```

I would need to see more complete code to know what is causing the error.

Comment: This should do what I need; however, I get the error: NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments. There are some missing values in the Time2.Feel variables. Is there a way to add an na.action command to tell R to fill in "NA" when that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

To expound on @thelatemail's comment, you could do this

```
dat <- read.csv(text="UniqueID, Time1.Feel1, Time2.Feel1.1, Time2.Feel1.2, Time2Num
1, 9, 5, 6, 1
1, 9, 7, 5, 2
2, 4, 3, 4, 1
2, 4, 5, 6, 2
3, 7, 4, 7, 1
3, 7, 6, 5, 2")


dat$Time2.Feel1 <- dat[c("Time2.Feel1.1","Time2.Feel1.2")][cbind(seq(nrow(dat)),dat$Time2Num)]

#   UniqueID Time1.Feel1 Time2.Feel1.1 Time2.Feel1.2 Time2Num Time2.Feel1
# 1        1           9             5             6        1           5
# 2        1           9             7             5        2           5
# 3        2           4             3             4        1           3
# 4        2           4             5             6        2           6
# 5        3           7             4             7        1           4
# 6        3           7             6             5        2           5
```

Doing that 30 times isn't very efficient, so you could use a loop:

```
## creating some example data which I think matches your format
nr <- nrow(dat)
set.seed(1)
dat1 <- lapply(1:15, function(ii) 
  matrix(c(sample(1:9, nr * 2, replace = TRUE),
           sample(1:2, nr, replace = TRUE)), nrow = nr,
         dimnames = list(NULL, c(paste0('Time2.Feel1.', 1 + 2 * (ii - 1)),
                                 paste0('Time2.Feel1.', 2 + 2 * (ii - 1)),
                                 sprintf('Time%sNum', 2 + 2 * (ii - 1))))))
dat1 <- data.frame(do.call('cbind', dat1))

#   Time2.Feel1.1 Time2.Feel1.2 Time2Num Time2.Feel1.3 Time2.Feel1.4 Time4Num
# 1             3             9        2             4             3        1
# 2             4             6        1             7             4        2
# 3             6             6        2             9             1        1
# 4             9             1        1             2             4        1
# 5             2             2        2             6             8        2
# 6             9             2        2             2             4        2
#   Time2.Feel1.5 Time2.Feel1.6 Time6Num Time2.Feel1.7 Time2.Feel1.8 Time8Num
# 1             8             8        2             1             9        1
# 2             1             5        2             1             3        2
# 3             7             5        1             3             5        1
# 4             4             8        2             5             3        2
# 5             8             1        1             6             6        1
# 6             6             5        1             4             3        2
#   Time2.Feel1.9 Time2.Feel1.10 Time10Num Time2.Feel1.11 Time2.Feel1.12 Time12Num
# 1             4              7         2              3              5         1
# 2             4              9         1              1              4         2
# 3             5              4         2              6              8         2
# 4             9              7         1              8              6         1
# 5             8              4         1              8              6         1
# 6             4              3         1              8              4         1
```

etc, etc

So you can start here. First you make the input vectors:

1. I call `xx` which is Time2.Feel1, Time2.Feel3, Time2.Feel5, etc
2. `yy` which is Time2.Feel2, Time2.Feel4, Time2.Feel6, etc; `xx` and `yy` are your two "choices"
3. and `zz` which is the "decision" column, Time2Feel1, Time4Feel1, Time6Feel1, etc

Then use `mapply` to do the indexing above but in a 1-1 mapping using those three input vectors with `mapply`. Note that `zz`, `yy`, and `xx` are all the same length

```
n <- 30
xx <- paste0('Time2.Feel1.', seq(1, n - 1, by = 2))
yy <- paste0('Time2.Feel1.', seq(2, n, by = 2))
zz <- sprintf('Time%sNum', seq(2, n, by = 2))
nn <- sprintf('Time%s.Feel1', seq(2, n, by = 2))


res <- mapply(function(x, y, z) dat1[, c(x, y)][cbind(1:nr, dat1[, z])],
              xx, yy, zz, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

res <- `colnames<-`(do.call('cbind', res), nn)

#      Time2.Feel1 Time4.Feel1 Time6.Feel1 Time8.Feel1 Time10.Feel1 Time12.Feel1
# [1,]           9           4           8           1            7            3
# [2,]           4           4           5           3            4            4
# [3,]           6           9           7           3            4            8
# [4,]           9           2           8           3            9            8
# [5,]           2           8           8           6            8            8
# [6,]           2           4           6           3            4            8
```

And then you can combine the results back. You would need to reorder them if that is important to you

```
## combine results into original data
cbind(dat1, res)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; I found a solution that falls more in my comfort zone as a novice R user, although I plan to work through your suggestion because I think you're right: a loop is likely the best solution.

Comment: @CarolTweten IMHO this approach is much simpler and easier to read (especially when you are getting into multiple and nested `ifelse` statements) when you know what's going on. think of a function with two inputs like repeat: `mapply(rep, 1, 1:3)` is just looping `rep(1, 1)`, `rep(1, 2)`, `rep(1, 3)` (recycling 1 since 1:3 is length 3). if the inputs were the same length, this would just map 1:1 like so: `mapply(rep, 1:3, 1:3)`. what i did above is just apply this concept to a (less simple) function with *three* arguments and three input vectors